# Rails query through association limited to most recent record?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class User 
has_many :books
```

I need a query that returns:

Users whose most recent book has :complete => true. i.e. If a user's most recent book has :complete => false, I **do not want them in my result**.

What I have so far

```
User.joins(:books).merge(Book.where(:complete => true))
```

which is a promising start but does not give me the result I need. I've tried adding an `.order("created_on desc").limit(1)`
to the end of the above query but then I end up with only one result when I am expecting many.

Thanks!

Comment: right. was trying to make it check :complete => true ? on only the most recent book record for each user but obviously that didnt work...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you aren't going to go with @rubyprince's ruby solution, this is actually a more complex DB query than ActiveRecord can handle in it's simplest form because it requires a sub-query. Here's how I would do this entirely with a query:

```
SELECT   users.*
FROM     users
         INNER JOIN books on books.user_id = users.id
WHERE    books.created_on = ( SELECT  MAX(books.created_on)
                              FROM    books
                              WHERE   books.user_id = users.id)
         AND books.complete = true
GROUP BY users.id
```

To convert this into ActiveRecord I would do the following:

```
class User
  scope :last_book_completed, joins(:books)
    .where('books.created_on = (SELECT MAX(books.created_on) FROM books WHERE books.user_id = users.id)')
    .where('books.complete = true')
    .group('users.id')
end
```

You can then get a list of all users that have a last completed book by doing the following:

```
User.last_book_completed
```

Comment: I was getting an sqlite syntax error "Around 'completed'" when i tried this. Looks promising though!

Comment: Oh, you might have named your variable 'complete' instead of 'completed'. Simply change the variable name.

Comment: I updated my answer to use complete instead of completed as well.

Comment: @pan..should the condition `'books.complete = true' be `'books.complete = 1'` or `'books.complete = ?', true`

Comment: If it's a constant and not user input, it's not necessary to sanitize it with 'books.complete = ?', true. 1 or true should both work as well, at least in MySQL.

Comment: @pan..oh..I didnt know SQL will give values both for `1` and `true`..i thought Rails was converting `true` or `false` to `1` or `0` while creating the sql query..thanks..

Comment: @rubyprince Only SQLite treats 1 and true equivalently -- MySQL and PostgreSQL do not. So for the most portable syntax, you need `'books.complete = ?', true` -- that way Rails' DB adapter can write the query properly for the DB in question.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser..I tried some queries in MySQL, and it seemed it was treating it same. I dont know if it differs in other cases, but for the query in question, both 1 and true were working in the same fashion in MySQL.

Comment: @rubyprince I had forgotten when I wrote my earlier comment that if the `emulate_booleans` setting is turned on, Rails will treat 1 and 0 like true and false (even if the DB doesn't). I'd advise not doing this, and using a proper boolean field instead: it's usually better to use the right type for the data being represented.

Comment: @PanThomakos, SUPER! Works also on polymorphic (`Status` class) with this tweak: `(SELECT MAX(statuses.created_at) FROM statuses WHERE statuses.statusable_id = #{statusable_id} AND statuses.statusable_type = '#{statusable_type}')`. Or maybe 8 years later 8) there is a better query interface for this...

Answer (score 15):

This adds a little overhead, but saves complexity and increases speed later when it matters.

Add a "most_recent" column to books.  Make sure you add an index.

```
class AddMostRecentToBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.change
    add_column :books, :most_recent, :boolean, :default => false, :null => false
  end
  add_index :books, :most_recent, where: :most_recent  # partial index

end
```

Then, when you save a book, update most_recent

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

  on_save :mark_most_recent

  def mark_most_recent
    user.books.order(:created_at => :desc).offset(1).update_all(:most_recent => false)
    user.books.order(:created_at => :desc).limit(1).update_all(:most_recent => true)
  end

end
```

Now, for your query

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Could also include and preload most-recent book this way for lists if you wanted
  has_one :most_recent_book, -> { where(:most_recent => true) }, :class_name => 'Book'

  scope :last_book_completed, -> { joins(:books).where(:books => { :most_recent => true, :complete => true })
end
```

This allows you to write it like this and the result is a Relation to be used with other scopes.

```
User.last_book_completed
```

Comment: This is by far the slickest answer

Comment: But will have to add something to mark the existing book records as recent (incase database already has some values.

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across a similar problem and here is how I solved it:

```
most_recent_book_ids = User.all.map {|user| user.books.last.id }
results = User.joins(:books).where('books.id in (?) AND books.complete == ?', most_recent_book_ids, true).uniq
```

This way we only use ActiveRecord methods (no extra SQL) and can reuse it when considering any subset of books for users (first, last, last n books, etc...). You need the last 'uniq' cause otherwise each user would appear twice..

Answer (score 2):

I cant think of a way to do it in a single query but you can do:

```
User.all.select { |user| user.books.order("created_at desc").limit(1).complete }
```

Comment: This is what I ended up implementing but I feel like there *must* be a cleaner way to do it with a db query. It just feels like a simple request to me...I would upvote you but lack the rep :/

Comment: I know man, my solution is very bad and generates (n + 1) query. But I was not able to find a better solution at that time. that is why I requested @pan to have a look at this question, and he indeed came up with a beautiful and right answer.

Comment: This generate N+1 problem with  actually you dont want in your app.

Answer (score 1):

based off [Pan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5263322/692224) but with a left join instead of an inner join, and no grouping:

```
scope :with_last_book_complete, -> {
  subquery = Book.select(:id)
                 .where("books.user_id = users.id")
                 .order(created_at: :desc).limit(1)

  joins(<<-SQL).where(books: { complete: true })
    LEFT JOIN books
      ON books.user_id = users.id
      AND books.id = (#{subquery.to_sql})
  SQL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be using scopes here - they will make your life much simple (this is a rails3 example)

In your book.rb model

```
scope :completed, where("complete = ?", true)
scope :recent, order("created_on ASC")
```

Then you can call `User.books.recent.completed` to get what you want

Comment: throws error: undefined method 'books' for #<Class:...>  -- I need to query against all users not an instance

Comment: @john..you cant call `.books` on User model..you can call it it on an instance only like `@user = User.first`

Comment: @rubyprince yep, completely true. you can't.

Comment: This will not satisfy the OP's criteria: "If a user's most recent book has :complete => false, I do not want them in my result."