# How do i create a query that selecting the last record by condition in a has many table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a "Has many through" relationship:

```
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :sales_status_histories
    has_many :users, through: :sales_status_histories
    has_many :status_sales, through: :sales_status_histories
end

class StatusSale < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :sales_status_histories
    has_many :users, through: :sales_status_histories
    has_many :sales, through: :sales_status_histories
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :sales_status_histories
    has_many :sales, through: :sales_status_histories
    has_many :status_sales, through: :sales_status_histories
end

class SalesStatusHistory < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :sale
    belongs_to :status_sale
    belongs_to :user
end
```

I want to select all the sales that has last specific status in the same query

I need to populate a panel with this informations

I'm doing this:

```
@status = StatusSale.where(id: [2,9,10])
@date = DateTime.current.beginning_of_month..DateTime.current.end_of_month

@sales_col_2 = Sale.distinct.joins(:sales_status_histories).where(sales_status_histories: {created_at: @date}).where(sales_status_histories: { status_sale_id: @status })
```

But this returns sales that had the status ids in any moment and not in the last

Answer (score 1):

You could use a "select" at the end if the number of element is not too big.

```
@status = StatusSale.where(id: [2,9,10])
@date = DateTime.current.beginning_of_month.DateTime.current.end_of_month

@sales_col_2 = Sale.distinct.joins(:sales_status_histories).where(sales_status_histories: {created_at: @date}).where(sales_status_histories: { status_sale_id: @status }).select {|s| @status.include?(s.sales_status_histories.last.status_sale_id)}
```

Else, this post might help you : [Rails query through association limited to most recent record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247886/rails-query-through-association-limited-to-most-recent-record)

-- EDIT --

I think you could first start by getting the ids of all last SalesStatusHistory grouped by sale_id, THEN filtering them by which have to right status, and from that list, get all your Sale.

Based on that post: [How to get the latest record from each group in ActiveRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289319/how-to-get-the-latest-record-from-each-group-in-activerecord), I think it could looks like:

```
@status = StatusSale.where(id: [2,9,10])
@date = DateTime.current.beginning_of_month.DateTime.current.end_of_month

@sales_status_ids = SalesStatusHistory.select("DISTINCT ON(sale_id) *").order("sale_id, created_at DESC").where(status_sale_id: @status).ids
@sales_col_2 = Sale.distinct.joins(:sales_status_histories).where(sales_status_histories: {id: @sales_status_ids})'
```

You could always merge the last two line in one big request, but I see no advantages.

Note: Some corrections are probably needed since I could not test it from where I am.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the number of elements can be very big, is there some way to optimize this query?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the DISTINCT isn't work in @sales_status_ids = SalesStatusHistory.select("DISTINCT ON(sale_id) *").order("sale_id, created_at DESC").where(status_sale_id: @status).ids

Comment: All ids are returning