# Check associated records for empty value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a post and comment model. A post has many comments. What I want to do is have a query that checks for posts where the last comment description is empty.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments
end


class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post
end
```

Without sql, this would look like this:

```
Post.all.select { |p| p.comments.last.description == "" }
```

N.B: This is a rails 3.2 application. `where.not` does not work in this case

Comment: I think you can find some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319400/want-to-find-records-with-no-associated-records-in-rails-3

Comment: @trueunlessfalse I updated the question to more closely mirror my problem. I don't think my answer is in this link

Comment: Okay, you're right, that is a different issue. I can not think of an easy way of doing it with active record. This looks helpful though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247886/rails-query-through-association-limited-to-most-recent-record

Comment: Even in your non-sql solution you should explicitly specify the order before calling last.