# Filter ruby model by second with multiple conditions - question attempt grades and unattempted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord, where-clause

I am building a question engine with Ruby, I have the question element working well - users can create and attempt `questions`, and their attempts are saved in a `question_attempts` table.

I am now trying to build a question bank feature where users can filter all questions by a few different options - tags, difficulty and the result of their last attempt (if it exists). Both the filtering by tag (via a separate `tags` table and join `taggings` table), and difficulty (a string of four options saved within the `question` table) work as expected.

I am having some issues with filter questions based upon the user's attempts. I need to be able to filter for three different conditions:

- **Correct** - where question.attempt.score == 100
- **Incorrect** - where question.attempt.score < 100
- **Not attempted** - where question.attempt == nil / does not exist

The `question_attempts` models `belongs_to: user` and `belongs_to: question`. The `score` from their attempt is saved as a standardised percentage float with a maximum of 100.0.

For the first two I can use a similar methodology as I have for the tags, both of these work:

`.where(question_attempts: { score: 100, user_id: current_user.id }`

`.where.not(question_attempts: { score: 100 }).where(user_id: current_user.id })`

I can get the questions that an individual user has not submitted a response to using the following line:

`.where.not(id: QuestionAttempt.where( user_id: current_user.id ).select( "question_id" ) )`

---

My issues are:

- **How do I combine these filter options?** I am trying to avoid writing a long series of `if else` statements, but will do this if required (I can do this without assistance, just want to check there isn't a better way before cracking on)
- **How do I limit the checking of results to their last attempt only?** i.e. if they have submitted a question response 2+ times I only want to check the result of the most recent. I would be tempted to use the solution from Mark Swardstrom in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247886/rails-query-through-association-limited-to-most-recent-record), primarily because I understand it, but am concerned it would be an inefficient method.

---

Thank you for your help

Let me know if you need more details.

---

**Models**

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
  has_many :question_attempts, dependent: :destroy
end

class QuestionAttempt < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Controller**

```
# Gather topics / tags
# This is working
if params[:topics] != nil 
  @tags = params[:topics].split(",")
end

# Gather difficulties
# This is working as expected
# If nil, then show all difficulties
if params[:difficulties] != nil 
  @difficulties = params[:difficulties].split(",")
else
  flash[:notice] = 'Showing all difficulties as none selected'   
  @difficulties = ["Untested", "Easy", "Medium", "Hard"]
end

# This is the element not yet working
# I can gather the options Unattempted / Correct / Incorrect from the params
# Not sure how to then join this with my question_attempts table
@attempts = params[:attempts].split(",") 


# Gather questions matching the filters 
if @tags == nil

  @questions = Question.joins(:question_attempts).where(difficulty: @difficulties, private: false, draft: false, approved: true).distinct

else

  @questions = Question.joins(:question_attempts).joins(:tags).where(tags: { name: @tags }, difficulty: @difficulties, private: false, draft: false, approved: true).distinct

end
```

---

## Current Solution

This is likely not the most efficient way of doing this, but it seems to be working thanks to tips from Tom Lord. Would welcome any constructive feedback / tips.

```
    def tags
  params[:topics]&.split(",")
end

def difficulties
  params[:difficulties]&.split(",")
end

  def filter

# Check for previous answers
if params[:correct] == "true" && params[:incorrect] != "true"
  @questions = Question.where( id: QuestionAttempt.where(user_id: current_user.id).where('score = 100').pluck(:question_id) )
elsif params[:incorrect] == "true" && params[:correct] != "true"
  @questions = Question.where( id: QuestionAttempt.where(user_id: current_user.id).where('score < 100').pluck(:question_id) )
elsif params[:incorrect] == "true" && params[:correct] == "true"
  @questions = Question.where( id: QuestionAttempt.where(user_id: current_user.id).pluck(:question_id) )
end

# Check for unanswered filters
if params[:unattempted] == "true"

  if @questions == nil

    @questions = Question.where.not( id: QuestionAttempt.where( user_id: current_user.id ).pluck(:question_id) )

  else

    @questions = Question.where.not( id: QuestionAttempt.where( user_id: current_user.id ).pluck(:question_id) ).or (
        @questions
      )

  end

end


# Add all other filters afterwards as they should apply to all    

@questions = @questions.where(difficulty: difficulties) if difficulties

@questions = @questions.joins(:tags).where(tags: { name: tags }) if tags

@questions = @questions.where(
    private: false,
    draft: false,
    approved: true
  )

@questions.distinct
```

Comment: To check their "latest answer", you could consider doing `order(:created_at).limit(1)`.  To perform the third check, where a user has not submitted an attempt, it's vastly more efficient to perform an **OUTER JOIN** than to query by IDs like that. This is, literally, what an outer join is designed for; and modern rails has a built-in method for it.

Comment: I don't really see a way to "combine" these queries (what does that even mean??); the only thing I can thing of is to define a *scope* with logic like `.where("question_attempts.score >= ? AND question_attempts.score <= ?", ...)` - so you could pass `0, 99` as params or `100, 100` as params. But based on the information you've provided, such a scope may be overkill.

Comment: Another thing you could consider doing is - depending on your UI design/requirements - consider restructuring the overall model: A `Quiz` is a collection of `Question`s. And a `QuizAttempt` is a collection of `QuestionAnswer`s (which can be skipped?). When showing the scores, consider the value of each `QuestionAnswer` *associated to a `QuizAttempt`*. This gives a much simpler and more meaningful definition for "latest answer" and "overall score".

Comment: Thanks for your tips Tom. I don't think restructuring the models will work, unfortunately, as questions can be taken without being in a quiz. By combining I mean exactly what you mention - the user may want questions they've answered correctly and incorrectly in the past - i.e. your suggestion of `.where("question_attempts.score >= ? AND question_attempts.score <= ?", ...)`. I was hoping to avoid creating a series of `if else` checks, but perhaps I could create a series of strings that I could `.join` with an `OR` statements. I'll have a play with the things you've recommended.

Comment: If you want a fourth scope for "answered questions" as opposed to "unanswered questions", then a straightforward **INNER JOIN** would suffice. (The opposite of an outer join, see?) A scope like I suggested would also work - but although it saves a few lines of code, it adds unnecessary checks against the `score`. But either way, there's no need for any `if` statements here.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I've managed to get it working (I think) due to your help, I've added the code to the bottom of my question. I imagine it's a terribly convoluted solution... would appreciate any input you have

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick pass at a cleanup of your current solution:

```
def tags
  params[:topics]&.split(",")
end

def difficulties
  params[:difficulties]&.split(",")
end

# ...

questions = Question.joins(:question_attempts).where(
    question_attempts: { user_id: current_user.id },
    private: false,
    draft: false,
    approved: true
  )

# If both are true, no need to scope query
if params[:correct] == "true" && params[:incorrect] != "true"
  questions = questions.where('question_attempts.score = 100')
elsif params[:incorrect] == "true"
  questions = questions.where('question_attempts.score < 100')
end

questions = questions.where(difficulty: difficulties) if difficulties

questions = questions.joins(:tags).where(tags: { name: tags }) if tags

if params[:unattempted] == "true"
  questions = questions.or(
    Question.includes(:question_attempts).where(question_attempts: { user_id: nil})
  )
end

questions.distinct
```

The key difference between my version and yours is that I *compose the query in logical components*, rather than attempting to write the whole thing in one go.

This reduces the overall length and complexity, whilst maintaining the same result.

You could further simplify this by defining **scopes** on the `Question` model, to move much of this logic outside of the controller.

*Note: I haven't actually run this code, so it may contain some minor mistake(s). Please test carefully.*

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot better for sure. I tweaked the logic for the params[incorrect] to also ensure that params[correct] was false (as otherwise it matched when they were both true). The only issue is that I am getting the error `ArgumentError (Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]):`. I've treid a few different things but still crops up - I thought the following would work (as I can't see any join!), it works when not inside an `.or()` - `Question.where.not( id: QuestionAttempt.where( user_id: current_user.id ).pluck(:question_id) )`

Comment: Fixed it in the end, it's not as elegant as your solution it's much more elegant than my original. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect what I'm doing now. Basically a load of `.where` statements, after using `.pluck()` to get the relevant ids. Thanks again for your help.